# Picking a laptop for applied maths

Tags: laptop

I'm going to study for a bachelor in applied maths in the fall, and naturally, it will involve a lot of programming, computer simulations etc. The degree I'm pursuing relies heavily on scientific computation and object oriented programming with Java, Matlab and Python. However, I don't expect my studies will require a laptop in the top range of computing power.

Thus I will need a computer (laptop) that is suited for such tasks, but also one that is lightweight and easy to carry around campus and has a long battery life. A good keyboard, screen, touchpad etc are of course highly desirable, as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for PCs that I should consider (I don't think Apple is an option for me). Being a student I'm not interested in going much above $ 1000, at most a couple hundred above. If you have any specific models in mind, that would be welcome, but I'm equally interested if you know about any specific brands that may have several well suited models.

Thank you in advance for helpful suggestions.
EDIT: I'm currently looking at the Asus UX305 or the UX303 series.

Answer (score 1):

ASUS VivoBook E403SA-US21

- Quad Core Pentium on latest process sips power and delivers performance
- SSD allows efficient and fast operation, large enough to dual boot if you need a linux on there
- Windows 10 delivers good power-savings and compatibilty
- 4gb RAM good enough for low-intensity programs and mild multitasking
- 14" screen - it's a lil' guy.

Looks like people are claiming it lasts ~14 hours on a charge, which would be impressive if true.